# Excel VBA Need to add comments to multiple cells depending on their value

Tags: vba, excel, loops, comments

I have a decent sized table, each cell depending on their value I want VBA to add a comment with the text I choose to show for each value.
For example: If value is 11 - the comment will show ACT Grid. **Note values are sometimes integers and sometimes a combination of letters and numbers (A1, B1, C1, 1, 2, 3, etc)**

11  ACT Grid

12  Device & Boarder Tile

13  CMHPII / USACE OH Sign-off

14  Drop Ceiling Tile

15  Trim Wall Devices

16  Install Casework

17  Install Flooring

18  Install Doors & Hardware

These are just a sample of the values in the table. Right now I have a command button that I'd like to have pressed to update the sheet each time it's pressed, that means remove any previous comments and replace with new. There will be many cells without any values and I'd like to make sure those don't have any comments. Here's my code, I had originally used ActiveCell but that only worked for the cell that I had previously selected. I'm sure my code looks empty since it's my latest compilation of attempted code. I'm not at all proficient in this language and looking for some help. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("D11:CY148")

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = 50 Then
            Target.AddComment
            Target.Comment.Text Text:="test"
        End If

    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values always an integer?

Comment: @newacc2240 it's either an integer or a mix of alphabet letters with. 1, 2, 3, A1, B1,  C1, etc

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what you are trying to do is to use Case Statement. An example:

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("D11:CY148")

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cell In rng

        Select Case cell.Value
           Case "11"
               Target.AddComment
               Target.Comment.Text Text:="ACT Grid"
           Case "12"
               Target.AddComment
               Target.Comment.Text Text:="Device & Boarder Tile"
        End Select

    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do I add this within the code I already have or are you saying just on its own? How will the range be selected?

Comment: Updated my answer with your code. You need to add your other case scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, nothing is happening when I run the macro? Any suggestions as to why?